# Detecting intersection of two UIView objects at different superview

Tags: ios, uiview

I've got a problem with detecting intersection of my `UIView` objects.

That's what I have used below:

For intersection two object I need to figure out how to translate one coordinates system from first superview to another coordinates system.

I've used this approach: `- (CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)rect fromView:(UIView *)view` described here [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html).

As I know it is very simple to use this method. But in the different cases it is hard due a little description in documentation (but maybe just for me).

This is my structure of subviews that is shown on image below. I have already got all methods for drag and drop object. But I need to figure out how to get intersection for `UIView` **A** and `UIView` **B**. Thanks for help.

[image]

Comment: Could you please describe the hierarchy in more detail? Does a single superview contain both views A and B?

Comment: +1 for the perspective skew on your illustration

Comment: thanks for response guys. so about superview - there are two different  superviews for A and B views. When I am dragging B view the coordinates is changing just related for superview where B view is placed. So for translate B coordinates to coordinates where A view is placed I need to use one of many convertRect method declaring in UIView class, after this I need to get intersection with converted coords and A view rect. Very simple to understand, but not very simple for make this stuff )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have implemented this solution:

```
- (void)putComponent:(NSNotification *)notif {
    // Catch B UIView.
    UIView *view = [notif object];
    // Convertation. [self superview] - is view wher A UIView is placed.
    CGRect convertedRect = [[self superview] convertRect:view.frame fromView:[view superview]];
    // Find center point.
    CGPoint point;
    point.x = convertedRect.origin.x + (convertedRect.size.width / 2.0f);
    point.y = convertedRect.origin.y + (convertedRect.size.height / 2.0f);
    // Find if CGRect (self.frame) contains a point (center of B UIView)
    BOOL contains = CGRectContainsPoint(self.frame, point);
    if (contains) {
        NSLog(@"intersect here");
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the `CGRectGetMidX` and `CGRectGetMidY` functions in [`CGGeometry`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: If you really want to test for intersection, it's not sufficient to test the **center** of one rectangle.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's not sufficient solution for all approaches. I using the center points of my object because I have many objects (views) that are located next to each other. So if I drag B view to another view I need to intersect it with a view where center points of B object located. So if we suppose that under A view we have another C view also and I need to detect intersection just for one of these views (A and C) so in this case I use center point that will intersect just one of views instead if I use rect of B view that can intersect two of them.

Comment: Better yet use `bool CGRectIntersectsRect ( CGRect rect1, CGRect rect2 )`.

Comment: @Matrosov Alexander you are awsome man.. I wasted 2-3 day on this prb.
Thank you..!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is equivalent to the code in your answer, but considerably shorter:

```
- (void)putComponent:(NSNotification *)note {
    UIView *other = note.object;
    CGPoint otherCenterInMe = [self convertPoint:other.center fromView:other.superview];
    if ([self pointInside:otherCenterInMe withEvent:nil]) {
        NSLog(@"intersect here");
    }
}
```

Comment: I know the poster's answer does the same thing, but in general, testing for one rectangle's center in another is not a valid intersection test.